# Reversing a string in C w/o using `reverseStr()`

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I'm trying to reverse a String (array of `char`) but getting this error:

> error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

Could somebody please help me out and tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char myString[] = "My name is Blalalalala";
   char reversedString[] = "";

   int count = 0;
   for(int i = sizeof(myString) - 1; i >= 0; i--){
       reversedString[count++] += myString;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(reversedString); i++){
       printf("%c", reversedString[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: data declarations arent allowed in for header in c89. to fix either specify -std=c99 or move the data type declaration for i out of the loop for max portability

Comment: You're accessing `reversedString` out of bounds and you need a compiler that supports C99 or higher.

Comment: ^ both of these things are true and need to be addressed in OP's code. Make `reversedString` into a buffer the size of `myString`, and initialize `i` outside of the loop construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue (*if we can call it an issue*)  regarding the warning here is

```
  for(int i = .......
```

you're declaring (and defining) `i` variable inside the `for` loop condition. It is only allowed on and over `C99` standard. Prior to that, all variable declarations should have been done at the beginning of the block.

You can force your compiler to enable `C99` by using `--std=c99` while compilation.

Just in case, you don't have the `C99` support, you have to move the definition of `i` outside the `for` loop condition statement.

That said, let's have a look at the *actual* issues in your code.

1. `char reversedString[] = "";` defines an array with size `1` only. later, they are not *expanded* automatically, so your current code access out of bound memory to generate [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. `myString` being an array, the array name represents the base address of the array, so may **not** want to write

   ```
     reversedString[count++] += myString;
   ```

Comment: so, basically in c I cannot declare variables inside the `for-loop`? @SouravGhosh

Comment: @Michael Nope, you **can**, but for that your compiler should be conforming to `C99` or above.